# Decode with a simple way a variable

Tags: javascript

I try to take a specific part of a url which I take using this:

window.location.pathname.split("/")[1]

The value is

```
p-%CE%A4%CF%8C%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%82-%CE%92
```

How can I decode it? Could be possible to make something like `window.location.pathname.split("/")[1].decode()`

Comment: Hi there @many5, please don't add "solutions" to your original question as you did in an edit. The correct way of acknowledging an answer as the "correct" one is by marking it as the accepted answer. More info here: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

> The decodeURIComponent() method decodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component previously created by encodeURIComponent or by a similar routine.

```js
var param = decodeURIComponent('p-%CE%A4%CF%8C%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%82-%CE%92');

document.write(param);
```

In your case,

```
decodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname.split("/")[1]);
```